# I am using Python Compiler on iPad to practice programs however cant see any graphical visuals

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-requests

Below is my program:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data=np.arange(10)
print(plt.plot(data))
```

The output is just an empty list.

```
[]
```

Comment: reread the docs for pyplot.plot. We don't normally print its output

Comment: For a non-interactive session you need a `plt.show()`.  `plt.plot` returns a list of plot line objects.